# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `opponent` on serializer `DialogSerializer`

Tags: django-rest-framework

I got an error after use a create method in serializer.py

Here is my error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `opponent`
>   on serializer `DialogSerializer`. The serializer field might be named
>   incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `tuple`
>   instance. Original exception text was: 'tuple' object has no attribute
>   'opponent'.

This is my serializer.py

```
class DialogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for profile feed items."""
    def create(self, validated_data):
        dialog=Dialog.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)
        return dialog
    class Meta:
        model = Dialog
        fields = ('id', 'owner','opponent')
        extra_kwargs = {'owner': {'read_only': True}}



class DialogueViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

serializer_class = DialogSerializer
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def get_queryset(self):


    user=self.request.user

    return Dialog.objects.filter(owner=user)

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    """Sets the user profile to the logged in user."""

    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
# def create(self,**kwargs):
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main problem is that `get_or_create` return tuple like `(object, created)`. So following thing should solve your problem.

```
 def create(self, validated_data):
        dialog, created =Dialog.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)
        return dialog
```